# scikit learn train_test_split function not working as expected

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am using train test split function to separate data for training and testing, but function assigns wrong label for separated  train test data. Instead of assigning label from expected row it assigns label from 2nd row from expected row. Please, Let me know where i am going wrong ?

```
data = pd.read_csv('To_Tanaji.csv')
print(data.columns)
print(data.shape)
#plt.hist(train["DiffCorrectLatRawLat"])
#test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

#np.polyfit(data['DistanceRaw2GPS'], data['DistanceCorrected2GPS'], 2)
Output= data.DistanceCorrected2GPS
Input=data.DistanceRaw2GPS

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Input, Output, test_size=0.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't suggest turnning off the `shuffle` parameter in your `train_test_split` function rather keep your `random_state` variable fixed for reproducible splits. It's better to split randomly than splitting say the top 20% of the dataset this can skew your data.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Input, Output, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 0)
```

If the split labels are wrong you should make sure the Output and Input variables are assigned correctly or not.

Comment: Got it. my actual entry in the table start from row no 2 onward. First row is for column indexing. Second row is for column attributes name. Actual entry start from row number 2 but pandas considering it as a 0th row.

Comment: Its not valid problem means

Answer (score 0):

The train_test_split function will shuffle your data by default. If you don't want this, use shuffle=False.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

If possible, provide your input data (scrambled or not) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Its really helpful for me.